# Forward and reverse integration from one solution to another in TFS

Tags: branching-and-merging, tfvc

I have just migrated my code from Perforce to TFS. Everything looks good but there are an issue which is Forward and Reverse integration from one solution to another. This is the show stopper for me.

There are two different solutions and 2 projects are common in both the solutions, but have different copies individually. So forward integration would be merging the whole application from sol1 to sol2 resolving the conflicts in common projects. After it gets resolved merge the code back to solution 1 (reverse integration). Point to be understood is only common projects need to be merged and everything else can be excluded.

Can similar setup be done in TFS?

Comment: sol1 and sol2 are branches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the exact solution which is more or less the first option Jesse you provided. Basically we need to create the common projects for one of the solutions and then branch them in another solution. At a later point in time we can merge them from solution 1 to 2 checkin the merged files in solution 2 and then merge from solution 2 to 1 and checkin the merged files in solution 1.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this scenario is possible in TFVC, but not very common. You have a few options:

1. Create a branch root at the solution level and merge the files from solution one to solution two. As part of the merge operation exclude the files you don't want to merge.  Later you can merge backwards and forwards at the folder level.
2. Create a folder relationship, but do not turn the folders into branch roots. This allows you to merge one folder with another folder at any time, but doesn't show these folders as branches per se
3. Create a branch root at each project level and merge each project individually. This has a couple of drawbacks (as you can't branch the whole solution in this case, as branch roots can't be nested).

Or you can approach the problem differently:

1. Create a separate solution that contains the common code and use package management ([NuGet package publishing](http://vsarbranchingguide.codeplex.com/downloads/get/801998)) to share the dependencies between both solutions (essentially creating 3 solutions).
2. Use workspace mappings to keep the common code in a single location in version control and map the code to different locations on disk. You can use compiler directives or configuration or different abstractions (interfaces, abstract classes) in code to compile the sources into different versions.

Comment: From Vivek: Hey Jesse thanks alot for your reply. I guess the first option is more suited for me cuz I'm already using nuGet packages to store my binaries.